# Href issue with pdf

Tags: visual-studio-2010, href

I have following piece of code.

```
<a id="hlink" href="~/Documents/ABCD.pdf" target="_blank">Document </a>
```

The pdf doesnot open on Document click. If I copy paste same path into new browser window, the document opens.

And the document opens on click of "Document" hyperlink as well.

`"http://localhost/...(the rest of path)"` as generated on click of hyperlink.

Is that something I have not added in href hence not allowing it to open on first go?

May be some security settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~ Works for links resolved on the server, if you want that to resolve you need to do

```
<a id="hlink" href="~/Documents/ABCD.pdf" target="_blank" runat="server">Document </a>
```